# Understand Type Erasure in Java

Tags: java, type-erasure

**How would one implement  generics *without* type erasure**? As I understand it, if I have `class Foo<T>`, the `T` is replaced  basically replaced with `Object` and the compiler only has metadata that helps it cast it to the right paramterized type.

But, if reification was  implemented, then the `T` would be the actual parameterized type (as opposed to Object)... But I don't understand how the compiler would then able to figure out if `new T()` is valid invocation (i.e, T might not have a no-arg constructor).

Comment: exactly it cant thats why you can get exceptions when invoking random constructors via reflection on top of that you can specify <T extends <object/interface>> to narrow down the type definition

Comment: by the way  this is not valid the compiler complains here : `class Test<T> {
 void t(T s) {
  new T();
 }
}`

Comment: basic syntax goes like this : `T newT = (T) s.getClass().getConstructor().newInstance();` no clue how to avoid the unchecked cast warnings though

Comment: You cannot avoid type erasure with generics. That's just how they work. Usually you're not passing radically different classes to a genericized class, though.

Comment: The way that C# does this is to clone the generic class at runtime, so that `Foo<Integer>` *is a different object in memory* than `Foo<Double>`. It basically treats generic resolution as a last-minute compile step.

Comment: @chrylis Ah I see... "It basically treats generic resolution as a last-minute compile step" -- wait, it's a compile-time step? Bit confused, you mention in your first sentence that the clone happens at runtime :)

Comment: Are you asking how erasure can be avoided in Java regarding generics, or are you asking how the compiler or runtime would be implemented if generics were not erased at runtime?

Comment: @nz_21 "CIL" literally means "Common *Intermediate* Language". It's compiled down to the .NET virtual machine, but the runtime still does further processing on it, just like how Java bytecode is then JIT compiled.

Comment: @johnathan *no clue how to avoid the unchecked cast warnings though* Like: `class Test<T> { public T build(Class<T> cls) throws Exception { return cls.getConstructor(null).newInstance(null); } }`

Comment: The `new T()` limitation is not directly related to type erasure. If you don't know `T` at compile time, you don't know whether `new T()` is valid, regardless of whether it's available at runtime. C# solves with `where T : new()` and Java could theoretically do something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java specifically, constructors are not inherited by subclasses, so as long as a given parameterized type `T` can't be narrowed down to a specific type, you wouldn't be able to run `new T()`, since Java is statically typed, **regardless of whether or not reification happens**. However, instantiation using `new` is *only one case* where classes are used.

### Instanceof

The most obvious use to me for generics that aren't erased is being able to use `T` in an `instanceof` expression:

```
class Box<T> {
   public boolean isInst(Object obj) {
      return obj instanceof T;
   }
}
```

There's also the idea of seeing if `T` is a superclass or subclass of other classes, or checking equality with classes.

### Static Methods

With reification, Java would be able to call `static` methods on `T` "correctly." Let's say we have the following classes:

```
class Parent {
   void doSomething() { System.out.println("Parent"); }
}

class Child extends Parent {
   void doSomething() { System.out.println("Child"); }
}
```

With those defined, then the following code...

```
class Box<T extends Parent> {

   void test() { T.doSomething(); }

   public static void main(String...args) {
      Box<Parent> parentBox = new Box<>();
      Box<Child> childBox = new Box<>();

      parentBox.test();
      childBox.test();
   }
}
```

...should print:

```
Parent
Child
```

but instead prints:

```
Parent
Parent
```

This is because `T` turns into `Parent` by erasure.

### Inheritance

Generic inheritance (as weird as it sounds) could (probably) exist:

```
public class GenericType<T> {
   public class Inner extends T {   }

   public static void main(String...args) {
      GenericType<MyClass>.Inner obj = new GenericType<MyClass>().new Inner();
      System.out.println(obj instanceof MyClass); // Prints true
   }
}
```